# TypeError: _l is not a function in Vite deploy in Github Pages?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite

I build a website using vue and vite, then also fetch from Nintendo-Switch-Eshop API. When I run in dev mode, the API could fetch successfully. But when I build and deploy in GitHub page. The API did not show and showing this error instead:

```
index.e6fd7be5.js:1 TypeError: _l is not a function
    at Proxy.mounted (GamesView.f6090e0f.js:33:112746)
    at index.e6fd7be5.js:1:19501
    at tt (index.e6fd7be5.js:1:12401)
    at Ae (index.e6fd7be5.js:1:12479)
    at Mn.t.__weh.t.__weh (index.e6fd7be5.js:1:19381)
    at so (index.e6fd7be5.js:1:13772)
    at oo (index.e6fd7be5.js:1:14079)
qi @ index.e6fd7be5.js:1
games:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

anyway you can visit this website
https://alexivaner.github.io/GamesLab

This is my vue code

```js
<template>
  <div class="gameView">
    <game-card
      v-for="game in games"
      :key="game.sku"
      :img="game.productImage"
      :name="game.title"
      :description="game.description"
      :id="game.sku"
      :price="game.price"
      :autor="game.softwareDeveloper"
    >
    </game-card>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import {
  getGamesAmerica,
  getGamesEurope,
  getGamesJapan,
  getQueriedGamesAmerica,
} from "nintendo-switch-eshop";
import gameCard from "../components/gameView/gameCard.vue";

export default {
  components: { gameCard },
  name: "GamesView",
  data() {
    return {
      games: [],
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log("GamesView mounted");

    getQueriedGamesAmerica()
      .then((games) => {
        console.log("GamesView getGamesAmerica", games);
        this.games = games;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("GamesView getGamesAmerica error", error);
      });
  },
  methods: {
    increment() {
      this.$store.commit("increment");
      console.log(this.$store.state.count);
    },
  },
  watch: {},
};
</script>

<style>
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .gameView {
    min-height: 105vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
}
</style>
```

Comment: it seems `getQueriedGamesAmerica` is undefined ... and there is a line in teh code that does `Ee.getQueriedGamesAmerica = void 0;` - so, waht is `nintendo-switch-eshop`

Comment: its npm package from here
https://www.npmjs.com/package/nintendo-switch-eshop

Do I need extra setting to do compilation before build?